# Flex row not wrapping

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, media-queries

I am using media queries to set a break point for a flex row, however these flex items within my container are not wrapping when shrinking the window.

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .child {
    min-width: 50%; 
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .child {
    min-width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? It works as intended on my end. Try to add a snippet to your question and check to see if it works there.

Comment: Your code works perfectly when I tried the same locally.

Answer (score 3):

Your css should for mobile first and use min-width instead of max-width

```
.child {
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100%; 
}

@media (min-width: 720px) {
  .child {
    min-width: 50%;
  }
}
```